# CSS class IMG inside div and span

Tags: css, image, css-selectors

Hi on beginning I have code like this:

```
<div class="123_test" tabindex="0" role="button">

    <span class="">
        <img class="" alt="" src="picturetopic"></img>        
    </span>
</div>
```

How can I style this `img` with `123_test` class?

Comment: You mean like `.123_test > img{ style of the image }` ?

Comment: img is not directly descending from div.123_test. Shouldn't it be `div.123_test>span>img` ??

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all you cannot start a class name using a digit, I assume that it's generating from somewhere as the classes are empty, but if you can, than consider changing it, like

```
class="name_123_test"
```

And use the selector below like

```
.name_123_test > span img {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

[W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

Comment: Is there a significant difference between `.name_123_test > span img` and `.name_123_test span img`? Also, do you know if you need to include the intermediate descendant, span?

Answer (score 5):

Why are your `class` attributes empty?

If you want to apply the `123_test` class to the `img` tag, just add it in the `class` attribute:

```
<img class="123_test" alt="" src="picturetopic"></img>
```

Or do you mean that you want to use the ancestor `div` as a style guide for the `img`?  In your CSS, you can reference the `img` as a descendant of the `123_test` class:

```
.123_test img
{
    // css rules
}
```

The space between the two identifiers means that the latter is a descendant of the former.

Comment: I agree, if you can specify a class name to the image itself that would be good. Your second example would cater to scenarios where images are dynamically generated from 3rd party & if consumer does not have the ability to specify the css class names

Answer (score 0):

You can't name a class beginning with a numer. So change your class name to `class="test_123"` or something that does not begin with a number.

And now you can style your img in this way:

```
.test_123 // here you put your class name after the "."
{
    // style your image here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, use better HTML markup for the functionality:

```
<button type="button" class="test_123" tabindex="0">    
    <span>
        <img alt="" src="picturetopic" />       
    </span>
</button>
```

Buttons of type="button" can contain text or an image. If the image contains text, it would be better to use css to create the graphical effect for compliance w/ accessibility guidelines and display across multiple devices.